# xinput shows two trackpoints instead of one (one is libinput)

Tags: xorg, xinput

I have been using a script to configure trackpoint for ages. It worked on my current Lenovo x230 laptop with Gentoo but stopped working probably due to some software update.

```
#!/bin/bash
trackpoint="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"

xinput set-prop "$trackpoint" "Device Accel Profile" 3
xinput set-prop "$trackpoint" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 30
xinput set-prop "$trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop "$trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2
xinput set-prop "$trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200
xinput set-prop "$trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 6 7 4 5
```

The error message is more than clear.

```
Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'.
To ensure the correct one is selected, please use the device ID, or prefix the
device name with 'pointer:' or 'keyboard:' as appropriate.

unable to find device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
```

It is easy to check that the error message is right.

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

So the questions are (1) why is there now two trackpoint records and (2) how to fix it. In the past xinput only saw one trackpoint and everything worked.

There is a workaround of using `12` instead of device name but there's no guarantee the id would be stable, especially when it only exists because of a bug.

I didn't find any useful resources on the web.

I realized there are two different Xorg input drivers, one called *evdev*, the other called *libinput*. I'm using *evdev* on Gentoo and I don't have any other input drivers compiled. I don't know how to properly check the list of kernel devices and how *evdev* and *libinput* treat them.

It happened again, with Lenovo x260 – But I seem to have unfortunately not copied the two trackpoint reckords and so you won't see that. :(

```
> xinput --list-props 11
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (297): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (298):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (299):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (300):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (301):  1545, 5399, 1333, 4521
    Synaptics Finger (302): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (303):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (304):   255
    Synaptics Tap Durations (305):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (306):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (307):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (308):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (309):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (310): 116, 116
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (311): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (312):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (313): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.034400, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (314):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (315):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (316):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (317): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (318):   1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (319): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (320):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (321): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (322):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (323): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (324):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (325): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (326):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (327): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (328):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (329):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (330):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (331): 73, 53
    Synaptics Area (332):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (333):  3472, 0, 4112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (334): 29, 29
    Device Product ID (293):    2, 7
    Device Node (292):  "/dev/input/event1"

> xinput --list-props 12
Device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (339):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (340):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (341):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (342):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (343):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (344): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (345): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (346):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (347):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (348): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (349): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (350):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (351):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (352):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (353): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (354): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (289): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (290):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (291):    0, 0
    Device Node (292):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (293):    2, 10
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (355):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (356):   1
```

The output above seem to be very different. Also at the time the output looks like this, the TrackPoint doesn't work, i.e. mouse doesn't move.

Related links:

- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/71205/fedora-22-split-my-mouse-into-two-devices-one-for-the-pointer-and-one-for-scrolling-how-to-fix-it/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755967/how-to-make-a-program-that-finds-ids-of-xinput-devices-and-sets-xinput-some-set/18756948#18756948

Comment: What happens if you do a `xinput --list-props` on those id numbers listed ?

Comment: After the last reboot I do not experience the problem but will check it when it shows up again.

Comment: @cesar The issue is back at least for this uptime. TrackPoint doesn't work now. Requested output included.

Comment: Okay, I probably didn't catch all the output that I should have before reboot. Sorry.